Could I invoke an ExtendedTask in R within eventReactive expression?
An example of a shiny app using an ExtendedTask is given here: https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/nonblocking/
It uses ExtendedTask's invoke method within observeEvent to start the computation of a long-running task. It means that the calculations are invoked each time the button is pushed, even though the results may not be needed or there was no change in the input parameters. Would it be possible to use eventReactive instead of observeEvent? If yes, how? If not, is there any workaround?
Below is a simple reproducible example where the eventReactive instead of observeEvent would be helpful. When being on Panel 1 and pushing the button refresh, I do not want to invoke prod_values until switching to Panel 2, and vice versa. Furthermore, if refresh is pushed again after the calculations are done with no change in the input parameters, there is no need to recalculate the results. In a classical setting (without ExtendedTask), such behaviour would be achieved by using eventReactive.
global.R
library( bslib )
library( future )
library( promises )
future::plan( multisession )

ui.R
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( width = 3,
                  br(), br(),
                  numericInput( "x", "x", value = 1 ),
                  numericInput( "y", "y", value = 2 ),
                  br(),
                  actionButton( "refresh", "Refresh", width = "100%" ),
                  br(), br(),
                  p( "The time is ", textOutput("current_time", inline=TRUE) )
                ),
    mainPanel( width = 9,
               page_navbar( title = "Test", id = "tabs", inverse = TRUE, position = "fixed-top",
                           tabPanel( "Panel1", icon = icon("chart-line"),
                                     br(), br(),
                                     h3( "Addition" ),
                                     textOutput( "sum" )
                           ),
                           
                           tabPanel( "Panel2",
                                     br(), br(),
                                     h3( "Multiplication" ),
                                     textOutput("prod")
                           )
               )
    )
  )
)

server.R
function( input, output, session ){

  output$current_time <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    format( Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S %p" )
  })
  
  sum_values <- ExtendedTask$new( function(x, y) {
    future_promise({
      Sys.sleep(5)
      print( "Sum done" )
      x + y
    })
  })

  prod_values <- ExtendedTask$new( function(x, y) {
    future_promise({
      Sys.sleep(5)
      print( "Prod done" )
      x * y
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent( input$refresh, {
    print( "Invoke Sum" )
    sum_values$invoke( input$x, input$y )
  })
  
  observeEvent( input$refresh, {
    print( "Invoke Prod" )
    prod_values$invoke( input$x, input$y )
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderText({
    print( "Display Sum" )
    sum_values$result()
  })
  
  output$prod <- renderText({
    print( "Display Prod" )
    prod_values$result()
  })

}


I have tried modifying my server.R (see below). At least, it triggers the calculations only when the results are needed. However, the results are still recalculated even though the input parameters did not change. Is there a better way how to achieve the intended behaviour?
server.R
function( input, output, session ){

  ...
  
  ReactSum <- eventReactive( input$refresh, {
    print( "Invoke Sum" )
    sum_values$invoke( input$x, input$y )
  })
  
  ReactProd <- eventReactive( input$refresh, {
    print( "Invoke Prod" )
    prod_values$invoke( input$x, input$y )
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderText({
    print( "Display Sum" )
    ReactSum()
    sum_values$result()
  })
  
  output$prod <- renderText({
    print( "Display Prod" )
    ReactProd()
    prod_values$result()
  })

}

